# Why am I getting this error with 3dDeconvolve when I run my AFNI script on an Ubuntu bash shell?

Tags: tcsh, nifti

I'm trying to run a variation of the [doDecon.sh](https://github.com/andrewjahn/OpenScience_Scripts/blob/master/doDecon.sh) **AFNI** script in the [OpenScience_Scripts repository](https://github.com/andrewjahn/OpenScience_Scripts) that will process the functional neuroimaging data for each of the three tasks I am analyzing separately, but I keep running into an error with the '3Ddeconvolve" command saying `gltsym` and `-fout` not found, fatal error.

[image: The error code is pasted in here]

I've tried making sure all my **AFNI** packages are installed, and I've set AFNI to run in the background, but this error pops up every time I try to run the script. Note that I'm working off of a Windows computer with a Linux shell and I know that can cause problems sometimes.

If anyone has seen this error code before or notes any problems in my script, I'd love to hear any ideas...

```bash
#!/bin/tcsh

if ( $#argv > 0 ) then
    set subj = $argv[1]
else
    set subj = s01
endif

3dDeconvolve -input rsem_scale.nii                            \
    -mask mask/mask_func_sem.nii.gz                      \
    -polort 1                                                                \
    -xout -progress                                                     \
    -num_stimts 11                                                           \
    -stim_times 1 stimuli/sem.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 1 sem                                                  \
    -stim_times 2 stimuli/sem_ctrl.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 2 sem_ctrl                                               \
    -stim_file 3 regressors/trans_x_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 3 -stim_label 3 trans_x_sem   \
    -stim_file 4 regressors/trans_y_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 4 -stim_label 4 trans_y_sem   \
    -stim_file 5 regressors/trans_z_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 5 -stim_label 5 trans_z_sem   \
    -stim_file 6 regressors/rot_x_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 6 -stim_label 6 rot_x_sem     \
    -stim_file 7 regressors/rot_y_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 7 -stim_label 7 rot_y_sem     \
    -stim_file 8 regressors/rot_z_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 8 -stim_label 8 rot_z_sem     \
    -stim_file 9 regressors/global_signal_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 9 -stim_label 9 global_signal_sem     \
    -stim_file 10 regressors/csf_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 10 -stim_label 10 csf_sem     \
    -stim_file 11 regressors/white_matter_sem_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 11 -stim_label 11 white_matter_sem     \
    -jobs 8  \
    # tells AFNI to run GLT based on label names
    -gltsym 'SYM: sem -sem_ctrl'                     \
    -glt_label 1 sem -ctrl                       \
    -gltsym 'SYM: sem_ctrl -sem'                     \
    -glt_label 2 ctrl -sem                       

    -fout -tout -rout -x1D X.xmat.1D -xjpeg X.jpg                                  \
    -x1D_uncensored X.nocensor.xmat.1D                                       \
    -fitts fitts.$subj.sem                                                       \
    -errts errts.${subj}.sem                                                     \
    -bucket stats.$subj.sem                                                   

3dDeconvolve -input rplaus_scale.nii                            \
    -mask mask/mask_func_plaus.nii.gz                        \
    -polort 1                                                                \
    -xout -progress                                                     \
    -num_stimts 11                                                           \
    -stim_times 1 stimuli/plaus.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 1 plaus                                                  \
    -stim_times 2 stimuli/plaus_ctrl.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 2 plaus_ctrl                                               \
    -stim_file 3 regressors/trans_x_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 3 -stim_label 3 trans_x_plaus   \
    -stim_file 4 regressors/trans_y_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 4 -stim_label 4 trans_y_plaus   \
    -stim_file 5 regressors/trans_z_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 5 -stim_label 5 trans_z_plaus   \
    -stim_file 6 regressors/rot_x_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 6 -stim_label 6 rot_x_plaus     \
    -stim_file 7 regressors/rot_y_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 7 -stim_label 7 rot_y_plaus     \
    -stim_file 8 regressors/rot_z_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 8 -stim_label 8 rot_z_plaus     \
    -stim_file 9 regressors/global_signal_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 9 -stim_label 9 global_signal_plaus     \
    -stim_file 10 regressors/csf_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 10 -stim_label 10 csf_plaus     \
    -stim_file 11 regressors/white_matter_plaus_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 11 -stim_label 11 white_matter_plaus     \
    -jobs 8  \
    # tells AFNI to run GLT based on label names
    -gltsym 'SYM: plaus -plaus_ctrl'                     \
    -glt_label 1 plaus -ctrl                         \
    -gltsym 'SYM: plaus_ctrl -plaus'                     \
    -glt_label 2 ctrl -plaus                         \

     -fout -tout -rout -x1D X.xmat.1D -xjpeg X.jpg                                  \
    -x1D_uncensored X.nocensor.xmat.1D                                       \
    -fitts fitts.$subj.plaus                                                      \
    -errts errts.${subj}.plaus                                                    \
    -bucket stats.$subj.plaus                        
    
3dDeconvolve -input rgram_scale.nii                            \
    -mask mask/mask_func_gram.nii.gz                         \
    -polort 1                                                                \
    -xout -progress                                                     \
    -num_stimts 11                                                           \
    -stim_times 1 stimuli/gram.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 1 gram                                                  \
    -stim_times 2 stimuli/gram_ctrl.1D 'BLOCK(2,1)'                          \
    -stim_label 2 gram_ctrl                                               \
    -stim_file 3 regressors/trans_x_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 3 -stim_label 3 trans_x_gram   \
    -stim_file 4 regressors/trans_y_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 4 -stim_label 4 trans_y_gram   \
    -stim_file 5 regressors/trans_z_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 5 -stim_label 5 trans_z_gram   \
    -stim_file 6 regressors/rot_x_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 6 -stim_label 6 rot_x_gram     \
    -stim_file 7 regressors/rot_y_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 7 -stim_label 7 rot_y_gram     \
    -stim_file 8 regressors/rot_z_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 8 -stim_label 8 rot_z_gram     \
    -stim_file 9 regressors/global_signal_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 9 -stim_label 9 global_signal_gram     \
    -stim_file 10 regressors/csf_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 10 -stim_label 10 csf_gram     \
    -stim_file 11 regressors/white_matter_gram_noHead_tmp.txt'[0]' -stim_base 11 -stim_label 11 white_matter_gram     \
    -jobs 8  \
    # tells AFNI to run GLT based on label names
    -gltsym 'SYM: gram -gram_ctrl'                   \
    -glt_label 1 gram -ctrl                      \
    -gltsym 'SYM: gram_ctrl -gram'                   \
    -glt_label 2 ctrl -gram                      \

     -fout -tout -rout -x1D X.xmat.1D -xjpeg X.jpg                                  \
    -x1D_uncensored X.nocensor.xmat.1D                                       \
    -fitts fitts.$subj.gram                                                       \
    -errts errts.${subj}.gram                                                     \
    -bucket stats.$subj.gram
```

Comment: I think you're missing some \ at the end of that command; you can't put comments or blank lines between things if you're using line continuation like that.

Comment: Removing the comment before the offending line should fix it.

Comment: It's `<blink>` **really** `</blink>` weird to give a `.sh` extension to a `tcsh` script. Threw me off, to the point where I voted to close as trivial user error. (Shell scripts should not have any extension at all, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments above, it may not be possible to use shell comments inside multi-line commands. In `bash`, the lines

```
ls \
   # comment 
   -lrt
```

do not work, but the lines

```
ls \
   -lrt
```

do.

In your script, the line

```
         -glt_label 2 ctrl -sem
```

should also end with a `\`, as there are 5 more options below.

Aligning those backslashes may look nice, but finding the missing one is easier without the extra whitespace.

Comment: This is using `tcsh`, not Bash. By brief experimentation, `tcsh` reads the string after the backslash as an argument, not as a comment. But yeah, the script appears to be broken. (Writing a script in `tcsh` in 2020 is pretty broken in the first place.)

Comment: Ah, so the original script was a mix of `tcsh` and `bash` syntax? I'm not an avid `tcsh` user myself... Apparently it lives on in `FreeBSD`.